# How to sum of values from Firebase Database in Kotlin?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Database with several purchases in Android app, points value is assigned for each purchase, then entries are showing by following way:

[image: FireBase Database]

When userId is log in, a button appears and when user click on it the "showInfoClient" function is called and it must show user and the amount of points. Code is:

```
private val database = Firebase.database
private val myref = database.getReference("compras")

fun showInfoClient(view: View) {

        val userlog = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.displayName
        val alertDialogInfo = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
        myref.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userlog).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :
            ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                var sum = 0
                for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    sum += data.child("puntos").getValue(Int::class.java)!!
                    Toast.makeText(this@Principal, sum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
        })

        alertDialogInfo.setTitle(userlog)
        alertDialogInfo.setMessage("Puntos: ") // + sum

        alertDialogInfo.setButton(
            AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK"
        ) { dialog, _ ->; dialog.dismiss() }

        alertDialogInfo.show()

        val btnPositive = alertDialogInfo.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)

        val layoutParams = btnPositive.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        layoutParams.weight = 100f
        btnPositive.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }
```

I have tried to use different options but i´m not able to set "sum" value on

```
alertDialogInfo.setMessage("Puntos: $sum")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Any code that needs data from the database needs to be inside `onDataChange` or be called from there. Code outside of `onDataChange` will (most likely) run before the data is loaded.

So:

```
val userlog = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.displayName
val alertDialogInfo = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
myref.orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userlog).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :
    ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        var sum = 0
        for (data in dataSnapshot.children) {
            sum += data.child("puntos").getValue(Int::class.java)!!
        }
        alertDialogInfo.setTitle(userlog)
        alertDialogInfo.setMessage("Puntos: ") // + sum

        alertDialogInfo.setButton(
            AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK"
        ) { dialog, _ ->; dialog.dismiss() }

        alertDialogInfo.show()

        val btnPositive = alertDialogInfo.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)

        val layoutParams = btnPositive.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        layoutParams.weight = 100f
        btnPositive.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
})
```

For a longer explanation see:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)

Comment: Thanks for all, problem was userlog not same that userId, displayName vs email, then i correct it `val userlog = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.email`